# How to restrict the number of items in flexbox according to screen size

Tags: css, reactjs

I am new to grid designing on website design

In my react project, I have a row showing 3 components. One is Leverage type dot selection, Two of them are input box, Loan amount and Loan Rate.

[image]

Right now, every things seems fine in full screen, but when I shrink it, you can see that Loan Rate is placed on the next line while Loan Amount was still on above line

[image]

But what I want is, when I shrink it, it is either like this(1),  or like (2) when it is super small

[image]

In(2), basically its been achieved with my existing css, when the screen is super small

Q: How could I either showing everything in the same line or showing one line with leverage type and one line with Loan Amount and Loan Rate?

Here is my code

```
.setting {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- There are many ways we can  break flex item in flexbox layout the one I have used here is `flex-direction:column`, this property sets every flexitem to vertically..

```css
@media(max-width:576px) {
      .flexBox {
        flex-direction: column;
        /*set all flexItem to vertically*/
        align-items: stretch;
        /* stretch will foce to take full width*/
      }
    }
```

- Meaning of **media(max-width:979px)** means, CSS inside of that code block will only apply to screen size lessthan or equal to `979px`. Means the CSS will not affect for screensize bigger than `979px`.
- Speaking about below code,

```css
.flexBox .flexItem {
    flex: 1 0 calc(100%/var(--number-of-items-for-midium-screen) - var(--gap-val)*2)
  }
```

- `calc(100%/var(--number-of-items-for-midium-screen) - var(--gap-val)*2)` here we divide `100% width` with the **number of items** we want per row and we minus `var(--gap-val)` twice because we have applied `gap:10px`, which applied both side of `.flexItem` so we minus it 2 times.
- And just to make CSS more friendly I have created CSS variables for
  `--number-of-items-for-midium-screen` <= Number of items in a row
  `--gap-val` <= gap between flex items in a row

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

:root {
  --number-of-items-for-midium-screen: 2;
  /*Number of items you want in medium screen(below 979px)*/
  --gap-val: 10px;
  /*Gap you want between flex items*/
}

.flexBox {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: var(--gap-val);
  margin: 10px;
}

.flexBox .flexItem {
  flex: 1;
  border: 2px solid #d6d6d6;
  padding: 10px;
}

@media(max-width:979px) {
  .flexBox {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
  }
  .flexBox .flexItem {
    flex: 1 0 calc(100%/var(--number-of-items-for-midium-screen) - var(--gap-val)*2)
  }
}

@media(max-width:576px) {
  .flexBox {
    flex-direction: column;
    /*set all flexItem to vertically*/
    align-items: stretch;
    /* stretch will foce to take full width*/
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="flexBox">
  <div class="flexItem">
    <p>Leverage type</p>
    <label for="static">static</label>
    <input type="radio" value="static" id="static" name="gp1" />
    <label for="dynamic">dynamic</label>
    <input type="radio" value="static" id="dynamic" name="gp1" />
  </div>
  <div class="flexItem">
    <label for="loanRate">Loan Rate</label>
    <input id="loanRate" type="text" />
  </div>
  <div class="flexItem">
    <label for="loanAmount">Loan Amount</label>
    <input id="loanAmount" type="text" />
  </div>
</div>
```

**Understanding how to break layouts in flexbox**

```js
const btn1 = document.querySelector("#btn1"),
  btn3 = document.querySelector("#btn3"),
  btn4 = document.querySelector("#btn4");
const flexBox = document.querySelectorAll(".flexBox")[0];
const flexItems = document.querySelectorAll(".flexBox .flexItem");
const preview = document.querySelectorAll(".preview")[0];
btn1.onclick = () => {
  flexBox.style.flexDirection = "column";
  preview.style.display = "block";
  preview.innerHTML = `.flexBox{flex-direction:column;}`;
}
btn3.onclick = () => {
  flexItems.forEach(flexItem => {
    flexItem.style.flex = "1";
  })
  preview.style.display = "block";
  preview.innerHTML = `.flexItems{flex:1;}`;
}
btn4.onclick = () => {
  const numberofItems = +document.querySelector("#numberofItems").value;
  if (numberofItems && numberofItems >= 1 && numberofItems <= 6) {
    flexBox.style.flexFlow = "initial";
    flexBox.style.flexWrap = "wrap";
    flexItems.forEach(flexItem => {
      flexItem.style.flex = `1 0 calc(100%/${numberofItems})`;
    })
    preview.style.display = "block";
    preview.innerHTML = `.flex{flex-wrap:wrap;}</br>.flexItems{flex:1 0 calc(100%/${numberofItems});}`;
  } else {
    alert("Please enter number of items you need from 1 to 6");
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flexBox {
  display: flex;
}

.flexItem {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
}

.bg-red {
  background-color: red;
}

.bg-blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.bg-green {
  background-color: green;
}


/*Just for styling*/

.buttons {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.buttons button {
  padding: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  margin: 10px;
}

.textInput {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.textInput input {
  flex: 1 0 75%;
}

.textInput button {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 0;
}

.preview {
  width: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: none;
  padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexBox">
  <div class="flexItem bg-red">
    <h5>This is flex box item</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="flexItem bg-blue">
    <h5>This is flex box item</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="flexItem bg-green">
    <h5>This is flex box item</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="flexItem bg-red">
    <h5>This is flex box item</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="flexItem bg-blue">
    <h5>This is flex box item</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="flexItem bg-green">
    <h5>This is flex box item</h5>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="buttons">
  <button id="btn1">Apply flex-direction to column</button>
  <button id="btn3">set all box equal size</button>
  <div class="textInput">
    <input type="number" id="numberofItems" placeholder="Enter the number of items you want in a row" min="1" max="6">
    <button id="btn4">set items in a row</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="preview">
  <h2>Applied css</h2>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, 
First, May I ask , max-width:768px means this rule only apply when width is less than 768? Second, how do I keep Loan Amount and Loan Rate ,like (1) , when the screen is not very narrow.

Comment: Apart from it, for 768 px , may I know if it is considered to be a standard medium for specific size of laptop screen?

Comment: sorry , i tried your approach, it doesnt work out as expected

Comment: I have changed my answer and recreated the problem and its solution.

Comment: Sorry may you also include the previous ans and make the new answer below it? like seperate both with a line ? So I may compare it. Thank you so much . Maybe add a line called edit, and then simply paste the new answer below it.

Comment: I have deleted that answer but this will  help you

Comment: it's ok , but I always found it hard to understand this statement , max-width:979px / sometimes min-width:979px ... May I know how to understand it easily

Comment: and  may you explain ... what is it here calc(100%/var(--number-of-items-for-midium-screen) - var(--gap-val)*2)

Comment: I will add discription to post for max-width 979px and calc(100%/var(--number-of-items-for-midium-screen) - var(--gap-val)*2)

Comment: You can read it now, second code snippet is just to understand flexbox layout.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247453/discussion-between-nikkkshit-and-ae-leung).